# How to set Apple Magic Mouse permanently with Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse

Recently I bought Mac and Magic mouse. I am new to Apple hardware. I  was trying to install mouse with mac. I installed it successfully. But whenever I restart the machine I need to configure magic mouse and pair with mac again and again.

Is there any way so that Mac remembers this magic mouse just like wifi names?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you set it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to continually pair the mouse after every restart, this indicates there is a problem.

First thing I would try is to power everything down, and then turn the mouse back on (small switch on the bottom) so that the mouse is "discoverable" before restarting. Ensure you follow these [set up instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2845) after restart.

Make sure you have installed all system updates. OS X 10.6.2, for example, fixed a problem with bluetooth pairing.

If this still doesn't fix the problem, you could try to Reset the System Management Controller (SMC) [(see this Apple support document.)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964)