# Permanently pair Mac with iPhone

Tags: macos, mac, bluetooth

I have paired a new Macbook Air with my iPhone, however after the Mac is rebooted, it asks me to confirm pairing. Is this a bug in Lion, or can it be permanently paired?

Similar issue [with a mouse](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15634/how-to-set-apple-magic-mouse-permanently-with-mac), but solution didn't help me

Steps to reproduce

1. Set up Bluetooth device, find iPhone, pair while having iPhone on the hotspot screen
2. Disconnect and connect to device. Works fine.
3. Reboot Mac
4. Connect to the device from the Bluetooth menu

Dialog pops up asking for me to confirm pin. If iPhone is in hotspot screen, it will also pop-up a dialog. I have to tap pair on iPhone then it's back to normal. After that it works until next reboot.

---

About system:

- OSX 10.7.1
- tried iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4
- macbook air (mid-2011)

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include how exactly you are trying to pair your iPhone and what version of iOS are running? It would help greatly in troubleshooting. In the meantime, go through Apple's article (it has a list of troubleshooting you can do) and see if it can resolve your problem: http://support.apple.com/kb/ts2756

Comment: I've updated question with more details.